# Неработающий слайдер owl carousel 2

Tags: php, html, css, битрикс, owl-carousel

См. [Вывод картинок анонсов инфоблоков в слайдере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1372741/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5). После внесения изменений, предложенных u_mulder и ВикторКарев, а также собственных изменений, получил следующий вывод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как добиться вывода слайдера.

В файле `scriptslider.js` задал (также такой же код задан в `footer.php`)

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".news-list .owl-carousel .owl-theme").owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        nav: false,
        responsiveClass: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        autoplayHoverPause: false,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                nav: false
            },
            480: {
                items: 1,
                nav: false
            },
            667: {
                items: 1,
                nav: true
            },
            1000: {
                items: 1,
                nav: true
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Я вместо `owl-one` использую `news-list` везде. (поменял все вхождения `owl-one` на `news-list`)

В связи с вышесказанным возник вопрос - обязательно ли для слайдов использовать класс `owl-item` или хватает просто использования обычных `div`-ов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменял версию jquery на более позднюю - помогло.